# Search engine issue

Tags: php

I need your help. When user enter plural word or adjective to find singular word in my native language: czech. For example: when user enters motorový, it should return motor (now return motorov) without ový, same when i enter motorce (return motorc). It seems like 2letter and 3letter check doesn't work for me, 1letter check works. U can try my code on [webiste](http://testinzerce.4fan.cz/test_s/index.php) . Thank you for you effort, time and good advices.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
<title>Vyhledavac</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="s_word" value="<?php $_GET['s_word'] ?>" /> <input type="submit" value="Hledat" />
</form>
<hr />
<?php
if(isset($_GET['s_word'])){
    $s = $_GET['s_word'];
    $s_word = $s;
    $l_word = substr($s_word,-3);
    if($l_word == "ovi" or $l_word == "ovy" or $_l_word == "ový" ){
        $s_word = rtrim($s_word,$l_word);
    }
    $l_word = substr($s_word,-2);
    if($l_word == "ce" or $l_word == "ku" or $l_word == "em"){
        $s_word = rtrim($s_word,$l_word);
    }
    $l_word = substr($s_word,-1);
    if($l_word == 'y' or $l_word == 'i' or $l_word == 'u' or $l_word == 'e' or $l_word == 'ů' or $l_word == 'ý'){
        $s_word = rtrim($s_word,$l_word);
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM search_test WHERE title LIKE '%$s_word%' OR message LIKE '%$s_word%'";
    echo "$query";
    mysql_connect("localhost","user","passwd") or die('spatne pripojeni');
    mysql_select_db("search") or die('nelze najit databazi');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'");

    $query = mysql_query($query) or die('spatny dotaz');
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $message = $row['message'];
            $website = $row['website'];
            echo "<h2><a href='$website'>$title</a></h2><br /><p>$message</p>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Žádné výsledky pro dotaz: ".$s_word."<br />";

    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with SQL.  Can you remove the tag?

Comment: Thank you for response but I think it not solve my problem.

Comment: But there is some mysql code in the middle :)

Comment: you didnt put header top enough; even above `<!DOCTYPE>` which is output too, inside php tags. Be sure to have not whitespaces before it also (etc. spaces)

Comment: You are right but i think query isn't problem.

Comment: Edited with header on top.

Comment: I removed it seems useless

Comment: You get no benefit from that for loop. You may as well do 1 character, 2 character, and 3 character checks in turn. It would be easier to read. Surely the simplest solution is to do the three-letter checks first, and only do the others if they didn't find a match?

Comment: If users can enter `motorový` or `motorce` why you dont just find these last occurences (based on an array, instead of if-else), remove them and then search? if i got that right..

Comment: It should find motor in database without suffix, i try to reorganize my code as Paul Gregory said.

Comment: OK, I rewrite my code, still without results.

Comment: shouldn't this `$l_word = $s_word[strlen($s_word)-3];` be something like `$l_word = substr($s_word,-3);`. The way you currently have it, it will only give you 1 letter into $l_word and not the amount you think you're subtracting. Which means `$l_word == "ovi"` will never match.

Comment: I changed it from strlen to substr, still bad results.

Comment: I tried `$s_word = html_entity_decode($_GET['s_word'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  $l_word = mb_substr($s_word,-3,mb_strlen($s_word),"utf-8");` With same results as before. It finds ový compare it but return wrong result motorový with suffix ový. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
$l_word = $s_word[strlen($s_word)-3];
```

Be something like:

```
$l_word = substr($s_word,-3);
```

The way you currently have it, it will only give you 1 character into `$l_word` and not the amount you think you're subtracting. Which means `$l_word == "ovi"` will never match.

For example:

```
<?php
$s_word = 'motorce';
$l_word = $s_word[strlen($s_word)-3];
echo $l_word;
```

Will return:

```
r
```

**[Live DEMO](https://eval.in/104630)** and what you actually want is:

```
<?php
$s_word = 'motorce';
$l_word = substr($s_word,-3);
echo $l_word;
```

Which returns:

```
rce
```

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/104631)**

Comment: yeah you are right i try to echo it and result were r. It get only one letter. Can you please help me how to get 3letters from end of my string ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3342042 `substr($s_word,-3);`

Comment: @user3342042 also I just tried your site and your IF's doesn't even seen to be working as the result of the query is `SELECT * FROM search_test WHERE title LIKE '%motor%' OR message LIKE '%motor%'`

Comment: Works like a charm on english letters but on czech fails. I don't know why, utf-8 is set properly.

Comment: I guess you will hve to use mb_substr or similar methods or convert it to regular characters before searching.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you only one character:

```
$l_word = $s_word[strlen($s_word)-3];
```

Try with substr().

```
$l_word = substr($s_word, -3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have problem with UTF-8, when i use substr. I tried following code: `$s_word = html_entity_decode($_GET['s_word'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  $l_word = mb_substr($s_word,-3,mb_strlen($s_word),"utf-8");`

Comment: It should work with mb_substr(). There is a typo in your if condition, check it: `$_l_word == "ový"` should be `$l_word == "ový"`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fully working solution but the road i would have taken (assuming a UTF-8 encoded file):

```
$word = $_GET["s_word"];
$removelist = array("ový","ce");
foreach($removelist as $entry) {
   if ((pos = mb_stripos($word,$entry)) !== FALSE) {
      $word = mb_substr($word,$pos);
      break;
   }
}
```

Now `$word` should be trimmed and ready for searching, otherwise you should add more to the list.